# Prove that $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ is a metric on any subset of $R^n$?

Tags: metric-spaces

to prove that $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ is a metric on any subset of $R^n$.

For this it must satisfy these three conditions,

> $1)d(x,y)=d(y,x)$

My response is: $|x-y|=|y-x|$.

> $2)d(x,y)\gt 0,d(x,y)=0 $ if $x=y$.

My response is: $|x-y|=\sqrt{(x-y)^2}\gt 0\;\;\sqrt{(x-y)^2}= 0$ if $x=y$ .

> $3)d(x,z)\le d(x,y)+d(y,z)$.

My response is: $|x-z|\le|x-y|+|y-z|$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: If it is true on $\Bbb R^n$ then it is true for any subset because all of those statements are "for all" statements, so if you've already shown them for $\Bbb R^n$, you have shown it for all subsets.

Comment: but how to assure that it is proved for $R^n$

Comment: It follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: $\sqrt {(x-y)^2}$ doesn't mean anything in more than 1 dimension.

Comment: Yes but how to prove it for $R^n $